# How to use AMD GPU to process data with tensorflow and keras on Windows 11 pc

Tags: keras, gpu, tensorflow2.0, amd-gpu, amd-rocm

I'm unable to use my AMD GPU for work with data in Python code and using TensorFlow and Keras in Windows 11 Pro.

I already tried some things like Intel plaidML and other third-party software but nothing worked. Also I'm using anaconda3. I don't want to download virtual box or Linux onto another disk only just to be able to run a ROCm. Is there another way how to use my AMD GPU without Linux or Intels plaidML ?

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same problem and spent some time googling. Assuming up-ward compatibility and in the spirit of sharing below what worked for me. I use Win 10 Pro, 64 bit, AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 5675U.

Now there is Tensorflow2. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) are the installation instructions. I used the pip instructions and had it installed in a couple of minutes.

```
# Requires the latest pip
pip install --upgrade pip

# Current stable release for CPU and GPU
pip install tensorflow
```

Beforehand I installed WSL2 in the Windows Powershell `wsl --install`  ( [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) ). This took a bit longer. Windows also has [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-tensorflow-wsl), it might be useful to somebody else.